# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306'

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I have simple docker file for micro app

```
FROM python:3.8.16-slim

RUN apt-get update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends make build-essential libssl-dev  \
    zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev \
    libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev git ca-certificates

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m spacy download xx_ent_wiki_sm

COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "run.sh"]
```

run.sh just calling python script that connect to localhost mysql

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
host=os.environ['host'], 
user=os.environ['user'],
passwd=os.environ['passwd'], 
database=os.environ['database'])
```

the `.env` file looks like

```
host=localhost
user=test
passwd=test
database=semantic_textual_similarity
```

I build Dockerfile using  `docker build -t semantic_textual_similarity:semantic_textual_similarity  .`

and tried to run it using

```
docker run --env-file=.env -p 3306:3306 semantic_textual_similarity:semantic_textual_similarity
```

and got following error

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306'
```

What should i pass to `Docker run` to make it works ?

Comment: Are you sure about `passwd=os.environ['host']`? I guess you mean `passwd=os.environ['passwd']`

Comment: `localhost` in this context is the container running the Python application; the database will be somewhere else.  Where is the database actually running?  (Outside a container on the host, in another container?)

Comment: You don't install mysql in the docker image. This means `localhost` cannot work.

Comment: @DavidMaze the actual db is on the host on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions:

```
1.check mysql is running in host
2.change the run.sh file change host to actual docker container name
    host='docker_container_name',
3. then, try to run Docker run again,
```